# Joomla 4 Smart Search: Extra database for indexing data

Tags: database, search, joomla, joomla4

I'm just about to migrate my site from Joomla 3 to Joomla 4. It's a pretty big website with thousands of articles that leads to problems using the new Joomla smart search.

The indexing of the articles for the smart search lets the database grow up to almost 2 GB. That's way too much. Just wondering whether anyone with the same problem figured out how to save the data for the component into an extra database what might be a solution for this mess.

As the old Joomla search won't be supported with Joomla 5 anymore, I'd like to avoid this alternative.

Comment: You might try [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.